# Problem with aligned environments in an enumerate environment

Tags: equations, amsmath, enumerate

I wonder how I can take this code

```
$\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\begin{aligned}
    \int\frac{dx}{\sin x\cos x}&=\int\frac{d(\sin x)}{\sin x(1-\sin^2 x)}\\
    &=\int\left [\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac12\left ( \frac1{1+\sin x}-\frac1{\sin x-1} \right )  \right ]d\sin x\\
    &=\ln|\sin x|-\frac12\ln\left | \frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x} \right |+C
    \end{aligned}$
    \end{enumerate}$
```

like this

[image]

while it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align the equations `aligned` environment at the top use `\begin{aligned}[t]` -- otherwise the `center` alignment is used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\dx}[1][x]{\mathrm{d}#1}    

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
\int\dfrac{\dx}{\sin x\cos x} & = \int\dfrac{\dx[(\sin x)]}{\sin x (1-\sin^2 x)}\\
&=\int\left [\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{2}\left ( \dfrac{1}{1+\sin x}-\dfrac{1}{\sin x-1} \right )  \right ]\dx[\sin x]\\
&=\ln|\sin x|-\dfrac{1}{2}\ln\left | \dfrac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x} \right |+C
\end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
\int\frac{dx}{\sin x\cos x}&=\int\frac{d(\sin x)}{\sin x(1-\sin^2 x)}\\
&=\int\left [\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac12\left ( \frac1{1+\sin x}-\frac1{\sin x-1} \right )  \right ]d\sin x\\
    &=\ln|\sin x|-\frac12\ln\left | \frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x} \right |+C
\end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will update this -- `\frac12` etc is no good style, in my point of view

Comment: +1. There's currently too much space, though, between the instances of `ln` and the opening vertical bar of the absolute-value expressions, as well as between the opening vertical bars and the "sin" terms; this happens because `|` is used instead of `\lvert` (for the opening vertical bar) and `\rvert` (for the closing vertical bar). Better still, since the `mathtools` package is loaded, set up the directive `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}` in the preamble and write `\abs{...}` and `\abs*{...}` in the body of the text.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for suggestions. I will edit it later on. If I should forget it: Poke me